# How can I execute multiple statements at once in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to execute multiple LOAD DATA INFILE statements at once using MySQL Workbench. However, they execute one at a time. Anyway of forcing them to run in parallel?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open a separate SQL editor for each LOAD command and run it there. While one command is running you can switch to the next editor and run the next command and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can`t run parallel statements in one session. You can manipulate data from different tables in 2 or more sessions and depending of isolation level you can manipulate 1 same table in different sessions.